# How to upgrade to Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, upgrade

Excuse my ignorance, but I've not done an Xcode upgrade before. I thought I'd simply go to apple, download the .dmg file, double click it, and voila! However, after doing this (the .dmg file is a 1.56GB file), if I run Xcode by clicking the icon at the bottom of the screen, when it loads, if I check the version, it still says 4.3.2. So obviously, I haven't done something needing to be done.

Also, I'm not duplicating the message anymore so I can't give an exact quote, but when launching Xcode I got a message that it didn't recognize the device. I presume this is my iPad, which was provisioned as a development device before I upgraded the iOS to version 6 on it.

Perhaps my question can be answered by simply pointing me to an appropriate document. The websites I'm finding all seem to be about problems after upgrading. I haven't got that far yet, I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have downloaded the DMG file, you will need to double click on it so it can mount the image file .In that dmg file there is the xcode file you need and copy that into your applications folder. If you already have a xcode app in there it will override it.

Otherwise if you are not a developer, it is indeed easier to just download it from the app store. Good Luck:-)

Comment: Thanks. I had downloaded the DMG file and double clicked it. I missed the part about copying it to the application folder. Meanwhile, I downloaded it from the app store, and that seems to have done the trick. I am a developer, focused on iPad/iPhone apps, but I'm relatively new to Macs. I never really used a Mac until I decided to develop iOS apps, so there is a bit of learning curve that gets me sometimes. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah there will be a few new things to learn - also note that when apple released beta's they will name the beta's different than the official app, so that you can run them side by side.

Comment: Regardless of having the DMG file, the correct way to upgrade to Xcode 4.5 is to download it via the App Store. The only reason you'd need to download it from Apple directly is if you need to run multiple versions, old versions, or beta versions.

Answer (score 6):

Download it from the App Store.

Comment: This worked, but, in light of the other answer, perhaps it was a waste of bandwidth considering I already had the DMG and I was simply missing a step.

Comment: Wasting bandwidth is a moot point. If you install Xcode via the App Store then next time there's a public Xcode/iOS update it will prompt you to update it automatically. This is far more convenient. Also - Xcode in 2012 is only about 1.6GB and the rest is downloaded after installation through it's settings which is common to the DMG version and the app store version.